# Grouping Sequential items in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So here's the deal, I'm using Neo4J 3.01 and I have a graph with nodes of type Action which have amongst other links and properties the following two properties:
Type: [Comment,Reply,Vote etc]
Date:[epoch timestamp]
I am attempting to run a cypher query that returns a sorted list of nodes ordered by the date field but collapsing (Collect?) sequential items of the same type
So for the following nodes:

{**type**:'Comment',**date**:1}

{**type**:'Comment',**date**:2}

{**type**:'Vote',**date**:3}

{**type**:'Comment',**date**:4}

{**type**:'Comment',**date**:5}

{**type**:'Reply',**date**:6}

{**type**:'Reply',**date**:7}

{**type**:'Vote',**date**:8}

{**type**:'Vote',**date**:9}

I would hope to get something like:

{**type**:'Comment',**actions**:[{**type**:'Comment',**date**:1},{**type**:'Comment',**date**:2}]}

{**type**:'Vote',**actions**:[{**type**:'Vote',**date**:3}]}

{**type**:'Comment',**actions**:[{**type**:'Comment',**date**:4},{**type**:'Comment',**date**:5}]}

{**type**:'Reply',**actions**:[{**type**:'Reply',**date**:6},{**type**:'Reply',**date**:7}]}

{**type**:'Vote',**actions**:[{**type**:'Vote',**date**:8},{**type**:'Vote',**date**:9}]}

I attempted a simple collect and order cypher query:

```
Match (a:Action) 
with a.type as type, a  order by a.date limit 20
return  type, collect(a) as actions
```

but this seems to collect each type in its own group regardless of the sequence, so the actual result is something like:
{**type**:'Comment',**actions**:[{**type**:'Comment',**date**:1},{**type**:'Comment',**date**:2},{**type**:'Comment',**date**:4},{**type**:'Comment',**date**:5}]}

{**type**:'Vote',**actions**:[{**type**:'Vote',**date**:3},{**type**:'Vote',**date**:8},{**type**:'Vote',**date**:9}]}

{**type**:'Reply',**actions**:[{**type**:'Reply',**date**:6},{**type**:'Reply',**date**:7}]}

Comment: The result you got is exactly what I would expect from that query. I'm not sure you're ever going to get where you want in Cypher alone unless you group on date, and even then you would get a different result than what you want.

Comment: This may be the expected result of the syntax I used, however I am looking for a way to achieve the given result using cypher

Comment: I don't think you can. This isn't a task that's particularly well suited to query languages. It's just sorting and grouping, and doesn't particularly care that the values it's sorting could potentially be seen as a consecutive sequence, much less where the gaps are.